# rxjs separate emitted values in the various arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, rxjs

My service returns one array. For example:
`return of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])` 
I subscribe to it and inside .pipe() I want to separate every 2 values to a different array.
For example:

```
let result = {
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6]
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should describe what you have tried before asking people for help in Stack Overflow.

Comment: You may also want to check [`partition`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/partition) operator. It's not exactly what you need, but something similar, so can be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bufferCount` to create arrays from your stream:

```
from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).pipe(
  bufferCount(2)
).subscribe(subArray => {
  console.log(subArray); // prints: [1, 2]  [3, 4]  [5, 6]
})
```